# Can a set of vectors span and be dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am taking a linear algebra course and i am a little confused about this concept if i have set of real vectors S={v1,v2...v5}can they span a vector space V even if they are dependent or do they have to be independent?

Comment: Yes.  If span $S = V$ then span( $S \cup \{v\}$) $ = V$ for any $v \in V$. So take any independent spanning set, put in a new vector, and you have an example of a spanning set that is not independent.

Answer (score 3):

Take a spanning set for your vector space $V$, say $S=\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ (all vectors non-zero).  Add in $v_1+v_2$.  Whether or not the original set was independent, the new one
$$
\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n, v_1+v_2\}
$$
still spans $V$ but is linearly dependent.  (If $S$ had only one element to begin with, then add in $2v_1$. Same problem.)